# number is not a function in gmaps4rails v2 with polyline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

I'm trying to use polyline with gmaps4rails 2 and can't figure out what the error is...

when I hardcode my polyline the map is displayed as expected.
However, when I get the data from the controller I get a "Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function"

following code with hardcoded polyline works

view

```
<script>
 $('#myModal2').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) { 
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map2'}}, function(){    
    polyline = [{"lat":49.9574400,"lng":-123.1201800}, {"lat":49.9465300,"lng":-123.0553700},{"lat":49.9598300,"lng":-123.0475400},{"lat":49.9750500,"lng":-123.0427700}];    
    handler.addPolyline(polyline);
    handler.bounds.extend(polyline[0]);
    handler.bounds.extend(polyline[ polyline.length - 1]);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    handler.getMap().setZoom(12);
  });
  });
</script>
```

**but this one doesn't**

```
<script>
$('#myModal2').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) { 
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map2'}}, function(){       
    polyline = <%=raw @hashroute.to_json %>;
    handler.addPolyline(polyline);
    handler.bounds.extend(polyline[0]);
    handler.bounds.extend(polyline[ polyline.length - 1]);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    handler.getMap().setZoom(12);
  });
  });
</script>
```

controller

```
def show
     @hashroute =[]
     @list.routes.each do |route|
      @hashroute << { :lat => route.from_lat, :long => route.from_long}
      @hashroute << { :lat => route.to_lat, :long => route.to_long}
     end

 respond_to do |format|
          format.html {render :show}
          format.json { head :ok}
        end

end
```

the @hashroute.to_json is populated properly and the polyline in the console looks the same as hardcoded version

console
code that works
[image]

when it doesn't work
[image]

any idea?

Comment: have you looked into what gets actually rendered? there is obviously a problem in the rendering...

Comment: btw if you dont use `var` in front of your variables, they will be global...

Comment: thanks...spent hours comparing the 2 and couldn't see any differences:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to close this question which remains open without reason, lets put my answering comment here:

You have to follow the right naming, replace `long` with `lng`